# When does Go allocate a new backing array to slice?

Tags: go, slice

When reading up on Go slices, I came across this behaviour in the context of the `append` method

> If the backing array of s is too small to fit all the given values a bigger array will be allocated. The returned slice will point to the newly allocated array.
>   <sub>Source - [Golang Tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15)</sub>

To understand this I wrote the following piece of code:

<sub>[Try on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QKQZlzrFPHj)</sub>

```
func makeSlices() {
    var a []int;

    a = append(a, 0)

    b := append(a, 1)
    printSlice("b", b)

    c := append(a, 2)
    printSlice("b", b)
    printSlice("c", c)

}

func printSlice(name string, s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("var=%v len=%d cap=%d first_address=%v %v\n", name, len(s), cap(s), &s[0], s)
}
```

Output:

```
var=b len=2 cap=2 first_address=0x414020 [0 1]
var=b len=2 cap=2 first_address=0x414020 [0 2]
var=c len=2 cap=2 first_address=0x414020 [0 2]
```

I would expect `b` and `c` to point to the same underlying array as they both are slices of the same length

---

But if I were to vary the same code for another length of slice:

<sub>[Try on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4fz7ybYw-vs)</sub>

```
func makeSlices() {
    var a []int;

    a = append(a, 0, 9)

    d := append(a, 1, 2)
    printSlice("d", d)

    e := append(a, 3, 4)
    printSlice("d", d)
    printSlice("e", e)
}
```

Output:

```
var=d len=5 cap=8 first_address=0x450020 [0 0 9 1 2]
var=d len=5 cap=8 first_address=0x450020 [0 0 9 1 2]
var=e len=5 cap=8 first_address=0x450040 [0 0 9 3 4]
```

In this scenario, `d` and `e` should point to the same backing array as they are again slices of the same length but they do not.

---

Why this anomaly in behaviour? When exactly does Go decide to allocate a new backing array to a slice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is simple: `append()` allocates a new backing array (and copies current content over) if the elements to be appended do not fit into the current capacity. Formally:

```
if len(s) + len(newElements) > cap(s) {
    // Allocate new backing array
    // copy content (s) over to new array
} else {
    // Just resize existing slice
}
// append (copy) newElements
```

So for example if len=2, cap=4, you can append 2 elements, no allocation.

If len=2, cap=4, and you append 3 elements, then len+3 > cap, so a new backing array will be allocated (whose capacity will be greater than len+3, thinking of future growth, but its length will be 2+3=5).

### Explaining your first example

In your first example you declare a slice variable that will have 0 length and capacity.

```
var a []int
fmt.Println(len(a), cap(a)) // Prints 0 0
```

When you do the first append, a new array will be allocated:

```
a = append(a, 0)
fmt.Println(len(a), cap(a)) // Prints 1 2
```

When you do another append, it fits into the capacity, so no allocation:

```
fmt.Println(len(a), cap(a)) // Prints 1 2
b := append(a, 1)
fmt.Println(len(b), cap(b)) // Prints 2 2
```

But this time you store the result slice in `b`, not in `a`. So if you do your 3rd append to `a`, that still has length=1 and cap=2, so appending another element to `a` won't require allocation:

```
fmt.Println(len(a), cap(a)) // Prints 1 2
c := append(a, 2)
fmt.Println(len(c), cap(c)) // Prints 2 2
```

So excluding the first append, all other append don't require allocation, hence the first allocated backing array is used for all `a`, `b` and `c` slices, hence addresses of their first elements will be the same. This is what you see.

### Explaining your second example

Again you create an empty slice (len=0, cap=0).

Then you do the first append: 2 elements:

```
a = append(a, 0, 9)
fmt.Println(len(a), cap(a)) // Prints 2 2
```

This allocates a new array with length = 2, so both length and capacity of the slice will be 2.

Then you do your 2nd append:

```
d := append(a, 1, 2)
fmt.Println(len(d), cap(d)) // Prints 4 4
```

Since there is no room for more elements, a new array is allocated. But you store the slice pointing to this new array in `d`, not in `a`. **`a` still points to the old array.**

Then you do your 3rd append, but to `a` (which points to the old array):

```
fmt.Println(len(a), cap(a)) // Prints 2 2
e := append(a, 3, 4)
fmt.Println(len(e), cap(e)) // Prints 4 4
```

Again, array of `a` can't accommodate more elements, so a new array is allocated, which you store in `e`.

So `d` and `e` have different backing arrays, and appending to any slice that shares a backing array with "another" slice doesn't (can't) change this "another" slice. So the result is that you see the same address for `d` twice, and a different address for `e`.

Comment: I understand now. I should have been looking at the properties of the original slice `a` and not the derived ones. I got confused comparing `d` and `e` when the actual comparisons should be between `a`-`d` and `a`-`e`

Answer (score 1):

I added another few lines to your example, have a look [here](https://play.golang.org/p/4uJVur3345d).

Look at the first `printSlice("a", a)`. The length is 1, capacity is 2. When you add an item there is no need to allocated a larger underlying array, so the same array is used for `b` and `c`.

Once the length goes beyond 2, (`d := append(c, 3)`), a new backing array is allocated for `d`. `c` remains unchanged. So when `e` is created the same process occurs with another new backing array created.